# Core-Graphics (iPhone) -Can we know whether a CGPath is closed?

Tags: core-graphics

Is there any workaround to know where a `CGpath` (created using an array of co-ordinates) *is closed*.

I was not able to find any suitable method in the header `CGPath`.

*I wish to track the path traced by user .If its a closed loop, then i wish to extract that part from the context. Something like masking or clipping the context but it should be user tracked clipping.*

Thanks!

Comment: [CGPathContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint) may help you! , [A sample project that could help you](https://github.com/ole/CGPathHitTesting) and [a discussion about it](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/)

Comment: Dear Bala, I appreciate your thought but that's not exactly what i was looking for.Also the link is useful, still it doesn't serves the purpose. Thanks anyways for your time.

Comment: it could be more helpful if you update and explain your question with more specific about what you are looking for..?

Comment: @Bala : I wish to track the path traced by user .If its a closed loop, then i wish to extract that part from the context.Something like masking or clipping context but it should be user tracked clipping.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, a path can consist of multiple subpaths. A new subpath is created when you move the path's current point without connecting the two points. For the path to be closed, all its subpaths must in fact be closed.

```swift
extension CGPath {

    /// Note that adding a line or curve to the start point of the current
    /// subpath does not close it. This can be visualized by stroking such a
    /// path with a line cap of `.butt`.
    public var isClosed: Bool {
        var completedSubpathsWereClosed = true
        var currentSubpathIsClosed = true

        self.applyWithBlock({ pointer in
            let element = pointer.pointee

            switch element.type {
            case .moveToPoint:
                if !currentSubpathIsClosed {
                    completedSubpathsWereClosed = false
                }

                currentSubpathIsClosed = true
            case .addLineToPoint, .addQuadCurveToPoint, .addCurveToPoint:
                currentSubpathIsClosed = false
            case .closeSubpath:
                currentSubpathIsClosed = true
            }
        })

        return completedSubpathsWereClosed && currentSubpathIsClosed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you've been stuck on this for the last 4 1/2 years, here is how to do it in Swift 3.  I have borrowed **heavily** from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374209/1677693).  I really just added the `isClosed()` function.

```
extension CGPath {

func isClosed() -> Bool {
    var isClosed = false
    forEach { element in
        if element.type == .closeSubpath { isClosed = true }
    }
    return isClosed
}

func forEach( body: @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void) {
    typealias Body = @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void
    let callback: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutableRawPointer, UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>) -> Void = { (info, element) in
        let body = unsafeBitCast(info, to: Body.self)
        body(element.pointee)
    }
    print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: body))
    let unsafeBody = unsafeBitCast(body, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
    self.apply(info: unsafeBody, function: unsafeBitCast(callback, to: CGPathApplierFunction.self))
}
}
```

And assuming `path` is a `CGPath` or `CGMutablePath`, here is how you use it:

```
path.isClosed()
```

Comment: Just because a subpath is closed doesn't mean the path as a whole is closed, see my answer for a correct implementation when the path consists of multiple subpaths.