# How to make player move to opposite side while is in a path?

Tags: swift, path, sprite-kit, move

[image]

I want that when touches began the player (red circle) moves to the opposite side of the circular path. I already made that the player follows a path, but I havent find answer to my question on internet.

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circulo")
    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 170)
    player.color = colorGris
    player.colorBlendFactor = 1
    player.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
    self.addChild(player)
    player.zPosition = 3

   }
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    if gameStarted == false {

        gameStarted = true
        moveClockWise()
        movingClockWise = true

    }

       }



   func moveClockWise(){



    let dx = player.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
    let dy = player.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2) , radius: 170, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
    player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to move an object in a circular path is to

1. Create a `SKNode` container
2. Create a sprite
3. Add the container to the scene
4. Set the sprite's `x` position to the radius of the circular path
5. Add the sprite to the container
6. Rotate the container

If you want to move the sprite to the other side or change the rotation's radius, simply

7. change the sprite's `x` position

If you want to change the direction of the rotation,

8. reverse the container's rotation

**Example Code:**

```
// 1) Create the container node 
let node = SKNode()
// 2) Create a sprite
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color:SKColor.blueColor(),size:CGSizeMake(20,20))
var rotation:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)
let radius:CGFloat = 50

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    node.position = view.center
    // 3) Add the container to the scene
    addChild(node)
    // 4) Set the sprite's x position
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(radius, 0)
    // 5) Add the sprite to the container
    node.addChild(sprite)
    // 6) Rotate the container
    rotate()
}

// Rotate the container
func rotate() {
    let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(rotation, duration: 4)
    node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action),withKey: "rotate")
}

// 8) Reverse the direction of the rotation
func reverse() {
    rotation = -rotation
}

// Stop rotating the container
func stopRotation() {
    if node.actionForKey("rotate") != nil {
        node.removeActionForKey("rotate")
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* 7) Change the sprite's x-position  */
    if sprite.actionForKey("move") == nil {
        stopRotation()
        let opposite = -sprite.position.x * 2
        let move = SKAction.moveByX(opposite, y: 0, duration: 3)
        let rotate = SKAction.runBlock {
            self.rotate()
        }
        sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([move, rotate]), withKey: "move")
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to add another sprite, it will also rotate?

Comment: If you add the sprite to the container, it will rotate. If you add it to the scene, it won't

Comment: Thanks Epsilon, but now how I do to add it on the center?

Comment: What do you want to add to the center?

Comment: I want to add an sprite to the center, but if I added in the scene it isnt at the center

Comment: `sprite.position = view.center`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could follow these steps:

- stop the `runAction` of your player:

You can do for example:

```
let follow = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction(),withKey:"followPath")
```

To stop do simply:

```
player.removeActionForKey("followPath")
```

- Re-build your path to have a new "moveToPoint" (the start point) wit the actual position:

To do it I try to use your code to make it understandable:

```
var myCircle : CGMutablePath! = CGPathCreateMutable()
let newDx = player.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
let newDy = player.position.y - self.frame.height / 2
let newRad = atan2(newDy, newDx)
let newPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2) , radius: 170, startAngle: newRad, endAngle: newRad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
```

- Mirroring the path:

To do this trick you can write:

```
var mirroring = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0) // flip horizontal
var mirrorPath : CGMutablePath! = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddPath(mirrorPath, &mirroring, newPath.CGPath)
```

- Restart the `runAction`:

Here you can re-launch:

```
let newFollow = SKAction.followPath(mirrorPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(newFollow).reversedAction(),withKey:"followPath")
```

---

**Addition**:
If you can add some nice animation like for example the jump between the point position and the mirrored point in the circle, you need to know the `CGPoint` destination (in the mirrorPath it will be the "moveToPoint" or the also the first point). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374209/1894067) you can find an extension to obtain all `CGPath` points so:

```
var mirrorPoints = mirrorPath.getPathElementsPoints()
let destinationPoint = mirrorPoints.first!
```

In the Sprite-kit framework there isn't yet a jumpAction between the available `SKAction's`, so you can create it with few code.
Usually the "jump" is maked by changing the Y coordinate, in you case your view is from high so you can do a zoomIn e zoomOut (scale).

Comment: Thanks Alessandro! Let me try it!

Comment: Right ,I'm here, when you want ask me.

Comment: "Mirroring the path" cannot convert value of type "CGAffine Transform" to expected argument type "Unsafe Points"

Comment: It keep telling that

Comment: Yes , there was a translate problem from objc to swift 2, look now and let me know if it work or not..

Comment: Thanks, let me try

Comment: But to stop the action I need to add another func?

Comment: You can check if followpath action is running so make jump else restar followpath

Comment: Ooooo yes, i get it now

Comment: I change my func moveClockWise to your code right, to add the key

Comment: let finalPath = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&mirroring) it tells me "cannot convert value of type "inout CGAffineTransform" to expected argument...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116330/discussion-between-diego-benitez-and-alessandro-ornano).

Comment: Have you try to change these property with var instead of let? Look my update in the path property

Comment: Samething to mirroring, I dont have try this code, it's just an example but it must work

Comment: This make the difference between Stackoverflow and working on commission.

Comment: Thank you too, it's a change of experience.