# SKNode follow path is always relative

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

I have a function that creates a path from a sprite and then runs `SKAction.follow(path, duration: 1.0)`. The path starts at (0,0) and ends at a target point. When I create this path for each sprite and run it, they all move along the same path, but relative to their start position.

They dont follow the path from their position to the same target position for some reason, they dont converge at the end point.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello Helium3, what about your issue :) , finally you solve it?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano - yes I solved it. It was an issue regarding translating points between nodes

Comment: Glad to know man, good luck for your project

Answer (score 4):

You could use the other follow path type method:

[image]

where **offset**:

> If **true**, the points in the path are relative offsets to the node’s
>   starting position. If **false**, the points in the node are absolute
>   coordinate values.

To find more details look to the official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417662-follow)

---

If you need to re-builds your paths to programmatically change some element (for example get all `CGPathElement`'s from the start `CGPoint` to the end `CGPoint`) you can look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374209/1894067)

Comment: Thanks for this, my issue was due to the target point not being relative to the sprites coordinates, with the action starting at (0, 0)

Comment: Oh, maybe related to the [conversion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483056-convert) of `CGPoint` between two different nodes